# Qt Script destructor of C++ object

Tags: c++, qt, qtscript

I have a subclass of a `QObject` which I can already create in QtScript using `var x = new Test();`

I made a constructor function and registered it using `QScriptEngine::​newFunction` and `QScriptEngine::​newQMetaObject` like this:

```
QScriptValue construct_Test(QScriptContext *context, QScriptEngine *engine)
{
    Test * ptr = new Test();
    return engine->newQObject(ptr);
}

....
QScriptValue constructor = pEngine->newFunction(construct_Test);
QScriptValue metaObject = pEngine->newQMetaObject(&Test::staticMetaObject, constructor);
pEngine->globalObject().setProperty("Test", metaObject);
```

I manage the object lifetime by myself (pointers to objects are stored in a static member of Test).

How can I make `delete x;` in `QtScript` `delete` the underlying C++ object? I know about `x.deleteLater();`(slot from `QObject`) but I can't use it.

Comment: I guess you could somehow create a a public slot on a QObject that would make the delete. Workaround.

Comment: @user2672165 You mean make a slot which does `delete this;`?

Comment: `delete this` would be a nice solution, but you could also make a special memory manager object. However, then you need to supply an identifier to specify what to delete.

Comment: Does your object have a parent? The parent object will delete all children automatically when it is deleted.